# Kazam & Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, gnome, screencast

I'm trying to install Kazam in my new Ubuntu 11.10 (64 bits version) with Gnome Shell and... nope.

Gtk-recordmydesktop does not work in Gnome Shell too.

I'd like using Kazam and I don't really know how to do it.  Any idea will be appreciated.

Regards. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kazam Screencaster in 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73622/kazam-screencaster-in-11-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use Kazam, try with more recent versions that I made available not so long ago in this PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~kazam-team/+archive/unstable-series

Comment: Thank you very much BigWhale, this solution fixes my problem definitely. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a tutorial about your problem.It works for me http://thelinuxvideo.com/?p=164
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

"GNOME 3 has an inbuilt software that allows you to record your desktop. This makes it very easy to create a screencast in GNOME 3. Here is how you do it ...

You can start/stop recording your GNOME 3 Desktop by pressing the Ctrl+Shift+Alt+R key combination.

The first time when you press this key combination, GNOME 3 will start recording your Desktop and any movements that happen on it. A red circle is displayed in the bottom right corner of the screen when the recording is in progress. Pressing the same key combination a second time will stop the recording.

After the recording is finished, a file named 'shell-%d%u-%c.webm' is saved in the home directory. In the filename, %d is the date, %u is a string that makes the filename unique, and %c is a counter that is incremented each time a recording is made within a single gnome-shell session. The recording is saved in the WebM format.

WebM is an open media file format designed for the web. WebM files consist of video streams compressed with the VP8 video codec and audio streams compressed with the Vorbis audio codec. The WebM file structure is based on the Matroska media container."

Source: http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-create-screencast-in-gnome-3.html

Comment: Those instructions say they work with Gnome 3, but that's true only if one is running the Gnome Shell.  Unity also runs on Gnome 3 (on 11.10) and the method mentioned in the article does not work in Unity.

Comment: That's a really useful trick! Thanks a lot, Dominic.  But this way doesn't allow recording my voice, which is something I also need to make some tutorials.  I'll try editing the webM video with Audacity in order to add my voice until a better solution appears.  Thanks again. :)

Comment: No problem! It's a cool addition to Gnome-Shell.

Comment: You should add this post as solved, even if it's a semi solution :)

Comment: Then by definition Dominic is isn't solved. Surely it should remain open for an answer for Unity users.

Comment: Not only Unity users, BrownE.  As Dominic said, this is just a semi-solution because voice is not recorded with GNOME SHELL's inbuilt software.