# Kazam Screencaster in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, screencast

I've been trying to find a good screen capturing program, and I've read some great reviews about Kazam, but they've all been with earlier versions of Ubuntu. Is it possible to install Kazam in 11.10? I've tried adding the unstable PPA to Software Sources, then running sudo apt-get Kazam, but no luck.

- I've tried the unstable daily build PPA, as that seemed to be the only one that was supporting Oneiric (it had packages for Oneiric, whereas in the stable daily build PPA, the packages were for Lucid and Maverick). http://launchpad.net/~and471/+archive/kazam-daily-builds

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I've pretty happy with recordMyDesktop. Recorded maybe over 50 screencasts with it in various configurations(full screen, single window, rectangular area). Pretty solid.

Comment: @Fossfreedom: I've tried the unstable daily build PPA, as that seemed to be the only one that was supporting Oneiric (it had packages for Oneiric, whereas in the stable daily build PPA, the packages were for Lucid and Maverick). https://launchpad.net/~and471/+archive/kazam-daily-builds

Comment: Currently 32bit Ubuntu. Planning on going 64bit once 12.04 comes out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the reason why Kazam Screencaster isn't installing in 11.10 is because 11.10 doesn't come with some of the dependencies that KS requires that came with previous versions of Ubuntu. I did some searching, and found another PPA for KS that a user created. This PPA works in 11.10 because it has the dependencies that KS requires.

https://launchpad.net/~vanhoof/+archive/kazam-scratch

**To install Kazam Screencaster in 11.10 using the PPA above, just enter the following commands in Terminal:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vanhoof/kazam-scratch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Here's a second Kazam Screencaster PPA that you can use.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bigwhale/kazam-oneric
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Answer (score 4):

Kazam is now updated on a more regular basis and more frequent releases can be found in the unstable ppa: https://launchpad.net/~kazam-team/+archive/unstable-series

I've made only Oneiric and Precise builds. Anything older won't be supported anymore and there will be no backports (at least not by me). The reasons are many, one of them is availability of libvpx or libx264 in Natty.

Recently I added support for GStreamer, PulseAudio and few more things. If all goes well, Kazam will be included in Ubuntu repo, before Precise is released, so no more PPA trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with Kazam installed in Oneric, it simply doesn't start, but to me it is the best screen recording on Linux and so I searched for the stand-alone portable version of it and it works perfectly. You can find the portable version [here](http://portablelinuxapps.org/audiovideo).

Just download it, right click on  properties and set it as executable. Double click it and it's done.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned today in OMGUBUNTU here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/kazam-screenrecording-app-fixed-for-ubuntu-11-10/

The version of Kazam for Ubuntu 11.10  is now available. It fixes several problems related to not being able to use in 11.10.

To use it in 11.10 please do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bigwhale/kazam-oneric
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Comment: Lol, a few weeks ago there were no PPAs for Kazam Screencaster, and now we already have 2.